# Python script for Cisco devices

Tags: python-2.7, scripting, cisco-ios

I want to extract running config from Cisco devices, but not getting desiered output from the code

## import the neccessary modules

```
import time, sys, getpass, paramiko
```

## setup the variables used in the script

```
ip = '10.155.111.5'
username = ""
password = ""
```

## establish an SSH session using local authentication to a cisco switch

```
remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password,         
look_for_keys= False, allow_agent=False)
print "Interactive SSH session established to %s" %ip
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
print output
```

## check current settings on SNMP

```
remote_conn.send("show run | in snmp")
```

## display the updated port config

```
output = remote_conn.recv(3000)
print "-------------------AFTER-----------------------"
print '\n'.join(output)
```

## close out ssh session

```
sys.exit("ALL Done!")
```

---

Getting following output

> > > ====================== RESTART: D:\user\SNMP.py ======================
> > >       Interactive SSH session established to 10.155.111.5

switch003#
-------------------AFTER-----------------------
s

> > >

Answer (score 0):

I'm using python 3.6 on Windows, the below works for me and should work in 2.6 as well. Your router probably requires a password for enable mode as well, hence the error. Try the below and let me if it works. I also use a sleep timer as sometimes the connection to the remote is a bit slow.

```
import time, sys, getpass, paramiko

ip = input('Please enter the IpAddress of the host:')
username = input("Please enter username:")
password = getpass.getpass('Please enter a password:')

output = ""
# Create a new instance of an sshclient
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# Set the missing host key policy to auto add the certificate
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=ip, username=username, password=password)
remote_conn = client.invoke_shell()
print("Interactive session established with {0}\n".format(ip))
remote_conn.send('\n')
remote_conn.send('enable\n')
time.sleep(1)
en_password = password + '\n'
#Ensure you send the enable password
remote_conn.send(en_password)
time.sleep(1)
print("{0}:Getting to enable mode was a success....".format(ip))
remote_conn.send("term len 0\n")
time.sleep(1)
output = remote_conn.recv(50000)
#Flush the output
output = ""
#Send a command
remote_conn.send("sh run | i snmp\n")
#wait a couple of seconds
time.sleep(5)
output = remote_conn.recv(50000)
print(output)
```